# Retention of configuration in Hofmann rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, rearrangements

Why is there a retention of configuration in Hofmann bromamide degradation/Hofmann rearrangement?

I would think that there should be an inversion of configuration due to the migration of alkyl group to the other side. Why is this not so?

[image]

Comment: The only group which can have a stereocenter in a substrate for the Hofmann rearrangement is the "R-" group to which the primary amide (-CONH2) is attached.

In all the steps of the reaction, the R group is never involved (no electron transfer is made from or to the R group), so the configuration is not touched.

Which step is not clear to you?

Comment: I mean the absolute configuration not the stereocentre. Basically, why the Fisher projection remains same.

Comment: I have added two examples from the book Solmon and Fryle.

Comment: Tip: Following the mechanism for the rearrangement given by your book, write with the curved-arrow formalism a mechanism of the rearrangement for those two molecules.